Why might it be advisable to avoid high-intensity activities if one has cancer?
Source

In an emotional announcement in Putrajaya yesterday, Chong Wei said his decision to retire was ‘tough’ but that he had to follow the advice of doctors to not involve himself in high-intensity activities.
He was diagnosed with nose cancer in July last year after the Indonesian Open.

It seems doctors advised Chong Wei to avoid high-intensity activities because of his nose cancer. Why might this be recommended? I'd have imagined that the idea is if you have cancer then you can't perform at high level, but the quote suggests it's the other way around.

I would imagine there could be several possible reasons but without knowing details of his medical care it would just be speculation.

According to common sense, cancer cause fatigue and thus it's much harder to take part in any activity, especially high-intensity activities. But without looking further into it and looking for actual articles/research it's also more of a speculation than actual answer.

@ShadowWizard yeah, but the article makes it sound like you should avoid high-intensity activities because it could aggravate your cancer (?).

That already depends which kind of cancer exactly, and also each person can react in different way, so doubt we can find a generic answer.

I agree, without being a party to specifics of the diagnosis we're shooting in the dark. A possible general explanation for the advice might relate to: Human growth hormone response to repeated bouts of aerobic exercise (physiology.org) - i.e. a known tissue (and therefore by implication cancer) growth-factor being released as a result of exercise.

It could be as simple as avoiding injury to the affected area, or the rigors of chemo. There's really no way anyone can answer this question.

@CareyGregory then write that as an answer. The question isn't specific to this particular case.
